# Module 'random' has no attribute 'randomint'

Tags: python, random

I have read other post while trying to solve this problem. All of them seem to say that the file is the name random.py but my file name is test.py

````
def getAnswer(answerNumber):
   if answerNumber == 1:
       return 'It is certain'
   elif answerNumber == 2:
       return 'It is decidedly so'
   elif answerNumber == 3:
       return 'Yes'
   elif answerNumber == 4:
       return 'Reply hazy try again'
   elif answerNumber == 5:
       return 'Ask again Later'
r = random.randomint(1,5)
fortune = getAnswer(r)
pint(fortune) ```
````

Comment: It's `randint` not `randomint`.

Comment: @yazou This is a simple typographical error, it hardly deserves “validating”. It deserves closing.

Comment: @donkopotamus : Okay. I removed my comments

Answer (score 1):

The function is **randint** not randomint. PLease change your code in this way :

```
import random
def getAnswer(answerNumber):
   if answerNumber == 1:
       return 'It is certain'
   elif answerNumber == 2:
       return 'It is decidedly so'
   elif answerNumber == 3:
       return 'Yes'
   elif answerNumber == 4:
       return 'Reply hazy try again'
   elif answerNumber == 5:
       return 'Ask again Later'
r = random.randint(1,5)
fortune = getAnswer(r)
pint(fortune)
```